# UIScrollView excessive content height when setting contentInset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, snapkit

I use following code (`AutoLayout`, `SnapKit`) to set up `scrollView`:

```
public lazy var contentView = UIView()
public lazy var scrollView = UIScrollView()

func addScrollView(insets: UIEdgeInsets, safeAreaRelatedSides: [Side]) {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalTo(safeAreaRelatedSides.contains(where: { $0 == .top }) ? view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top : view.snp.top)
        make.left.equalTo(safeAreaRelatedSides.contains(where: { $0 == .left }) ? view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.left : view.snp.left)
        make.right.equalTo(safeAreaRelatedSides.contains(where: { $0 == .right }) ? view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.right : view.snp.right)
        make.bottom.equalTo(safeAreaRelatedSides.contains(where: { $0 == .bottom }) ? view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.bottom : view.snp.bottom)
    }
    contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(insets.top)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().inset(insets.left)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(insets.right)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(insets.bottom).priority(250)
        make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview().priority(250)
    }
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

It works great. But When I want scroll view's bottom constraint to depend on superview and not its safe area (to let excessive content height be visible below safe area), I call:

```
addScrollView(insets: someValue, safeAreaRelatedSides: [.top, .left, .right])
scrollView.contentInset.bottom = UIApplication.shared.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

In result, `contentView` layouts its height as:

```
expectedContentViewHeight + scrollView.contentInset.bottom
```

A view with lowest `contenHuggingPriority` gets stretched by `scrollView.contentInset.bottom` more than it should. And now `scrollView.contentSize.height` exceeds `scrollView.bounds.height` with nothing forcing that.
This only happens when contentView height is less than screen height.

First screenshot represents initial UI. Second one - after scrolling to the very bottom

[image][image]

What can I do to prevent contentView height from this excessive growing?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... from the images you posted, it appears your scroll view's UI elements are slightly taller than the scroll view's frame, and you get the expected scrolling. What height is excessive?

Comment: TextView's height is not constrainted, so there is nothing forcing scrollView's content size to exceed scrollView's frame height. I expect these values to be equal in this case

Comment: Well, in your two images, the UI elements are the exact same heights and spacing... so it's not clear what is "not right." It might help if you dump SnapKit and use standard constraint syntax -- making sure you constrain to the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`. Would also help if you put up a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: First image is initial UI on opening the screen. Second one - after scrolling. I attached it to show that contentView height exceeds scrollView's height for no reason

Comment: The constraints on your `contentView` don't look right... it should be constrained to the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide` not `.equalToSuperview()`. You said *"TextView's height is not constrainted"* ... but if that's the case, it should have no height at all. Without seeing your other constraints it's tough to figure out what's going on.